# Separate title in NavigationBar and navigation buttons

Tags: ios, uinavigationcontroller, xamarin.ios, uinavigationbar

Hey, I have a stack of `UIViewController`s inside of a `UINavigationController`. Usually the title (or the NavigationItem‘s title) decides about both the title that is displayed in the NavigationBar (displayed at the top) *and* all the navigation buttons, for example the back-buttons in the navigation bar itself.

Now I plan to put a bit more information into the NavigationBar‘s title, while still keeping those button labels short and concise (for example the view‘s title is “<Customer name> Overview”, while the buttons should just show “Overview”).

I am currently trying to achieve this by changing the NavigationItem‘s title on `ViewWillAppear` and `ViewWillDisappear`. This works well, but one can see the moments where the text changes (probably due to the animation). I‘ve tried different combinations with `ViewDidAppear` and `ViewDidDisappear` as well, but the effect was the best with just the `Will` methods. An example code for this is shown below (the `Example` class is pushed to a UINavigationController).

Is there a better way to achive this? Maybe with simply changing the button titles *only* or with just directly changing the navigation‘s title? Or can I maybe prevent the standard mechanisms from copying the title to all other instances?

```
public class Example : UIViewController
{
    private int depth;

    public Example ( int depth = 0 )
    {
        this.depth = depth;
        this.Title = "Title";
    }

    public override void ViewDidLoad ()
    {
        base.ViewDidLoad();

        UIButton btn = new UIButton( new RectangleF( 100, 100, 300, 50 ) );
        btn.SetTitle( "Duplicate me!", UIControlState.Normal );
        btn.TouchDown += delegate(object sender, EventArgs e) {
            NavigationController.PushViewController( new Example( depth + 1 ), true );
        };
        View.Add( btn );
    }

    public override void ViewWillAppear ( bool animated )
    {
        base.ViewWillAppear( animated );
        this.NavigationItem.Title = String.Format( "Title / {0}", depth );
    }

    public override void ViewWillDisappear ( bool animated )
    {
        base.ViewWillDisappear( animated );
        this.NavigationItem.Title = "Title";
    }
}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If I understand you correctly, I think there's a ready-made for this:

Set backBarButtonItem on your view controller's navigation item.

Comment: That requires however that I set the button title in the *next* view; so I can‘t change the button title for view A inside its controller, but have to do it in every view I might push to the navigation from A. So I would need to change every *possible* subordinated view controller to both check the parent controller and update the button based on which parent controller there is.

Comment: No, you set backBarButtonItem on view controller A. "backBarButtonItem" defines what view controller B will show if A is the previous view controller. A bit counter-intuitive perhaps, but there you go.

Comment: Wow, great. That really worked! Didn‘t expect it to work like that. Thank you very much!