# Change "back" NavigationItem text in Monotouch?

Tags: xamarin.ios, uinavigationitem

Is it possible to change the "Back" button text in a `NavigationItem`? At present, the caption of the back button assumes the title of the previous layer in the navigation stack, which is expected.

However, the `NavigationItem`'s `LeftBarButtonItem` can be changed using code such as this:

```
UIBarButtonItem backButton = new UIBarButtonItem("Back", UIBarButtonItemStyle.Plain, null);
myNewView.NavigationItem.SetLeftBarButtonItem(backButton, true);
```

This works and the back button is displayed as expected, but the button is a square and does not navigate back to the previous layer as expected. I'm guessing that the correct event needs to be assigned to it, but I have no idea what it should be.

How would one go about ensuring that the new `UIBarButtonItem` has the correct event and arrow shape?

**Note**: I have also tried re-using the `LeftBarButtonItem' as suggested in this [SO question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2846539/adding-back-button-to-navigation-bar), but I still don't know how to customize the button caption. I am probably just missing the obvious.

Thanks!

Comment: First obvious thing to change is to assign to `BackBarButtonItem` and not `LeftBarButtonItem`, but after `viewDidLoad` it is still not initialized.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Set the title on the previous viewcontrollers navigationitem. I answered this before and will look up the link.

Ah, yes: [Separate title in NavigationBar and navigation buttons](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5338547/separate-title-in-navigationbar-and-navigation-buttons/5339862#5339862)

Comment: So for completeness sake, this is what you are supposed to do: `controller.NavigationItem.BackBarButtonItem = new UIBarButtonItem("Back", UIBarButtonItemStyle.Plain, null)`