# MvvmCross UINavigationController customise navigationBar

Tags: uinavigationcontroller, xamarin.ios, uinavigationbar, mvvmcross

Further to my experiences with MvvmCross, I've managed to build an app for iPhone which starts with a TabBarController. I can also successfully navigate within each tab to deeper levels. The problems start when I want to customise the navigationBar on the deeper levels - setting the backButton colours, etc. The code I use for navigation is the standard viewModel code -

```
this.RequestNavigate<InJourneyViewModel>();
```

…which works fine, but I can't do anything to the navigated-to view's navBar, other than set its title.

Any thoughts or advice appreciated!

Comment: Please don't use ", etc." - post the code that's failing :) Also worth adding MonoTouch tag to these questions.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think it might help if you posted some more of your code that is failing.

My suspicion is that the problem is a more generic Cocoa, MonoTouch and/or backbarbutton problem.

I've just played with the ViewDidLoad code in MapView.cs in https://github.com/slodge/MvvmCross/tree/master/Sample%20-%20CirriousConference/Cirrious.Conference.UI.Touch

At the end of this, I was able to add some bar button changes like:

```
        var leftButton = new UIBarButtonItem("FooBar", UIBarButtonItemStyle.Bordered, null);
        leftButton.TintColor = UIColor.Green;
        NavigationItem.SetLeftBarButtonItem(leftButton, false);
        NavigationItem.RightBarButtonItem.TintColor = UIColor.Red;
```

Which resulted in:

[image: four]

Alternatively, by placing code in the WelcomeView:

```
        var leftButton = new UIBarButtonItem("FooBar", UIBarButtonItemStyle.Bordered, null);
        leftButton.TintColor = UIColor.Green;
        NavigationItem.BackBarButton = leftButton;
```

Then I succeed in achieving:

[image: three]

Alternatively, by using code like:

```
        UIBarButtonItem.AppearanceWhenContainedIn(typeof(UINavigationBar)).TintColor = UIColor.Blue;
```

Then this enabled me to customise all the navigation bar buttons like:

[image: two]

---

At one point, I also managed to achieve:

[image: one]

... but sadly I've genuinely no idea which code combo gave me that! If your problem is with back buttons in particular, then I think you will need to dig around other questions and/or post some code and hope someone can help - there's lots of posts about how to do this, but I can't quite figure out what they all mean for MonoTouch - e.g. [Separate title in NavigationBar and navigation buttons](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5338547/separate-title-in-navigationbar-and-navigation-buttons/5339862#5339862)

Comment: Thanks Stuart - your solutions work fine, it was just a question of putting the code in the right place, I'd sort of forgotten that you set the NavigationItem properties from the view you're going from... Too much use of the StoryBoard in Xcode makes you lazy!

Comment: Related, but if you'd like me to post a different question, let me know - how would I navigate to a modal view, using something like this.RequestNavigate<MyViewModel>(); ?

Comment: For general StackOverflow etiquette, try http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/faq - chat within questions is definitely frowned upon - write good single-purpose questions and answers if you can. Before asking it's also a good idea to try searching first: http://stackoverflow.com/search?q=mvvmcross+modal might help. If you do need chat then occasional occupancy at http://jabbr.net/#/rooms/mvvmcross - hope that helps :)